# Replacing part of an object's name with object.name.replace?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

So this is a fairly straight forward thing I want to do. Basically I've got a mesh named XXXX_HP and I want it to find the "_HP" and replace that with "_LP"

I've looked through the various object.name functions and `object.name.replace()` seemed the most obvious to use, but it doesn't seem to do what I expected it to do.

```
import bpy

bpy.context.object.name.replace("_HP", "_LP")
```

Comment: Created and add-on for find/replace, copy/paste and auto naming: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace is a string function that comes from python's string object.
Since an object's name is a string property class, that inherits some props and methods from python's built in string class, it also gets the replace method.

The string replace method doesn't replace in place, but returns a string with the replacement applied. Which means that what you actually need to do is:

```
bpy.context.object.name = bpy.context.object.name.replace("_HP", "_LP")
```

Comment: Wow.. I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @TLousky's answer, a few more variants to achieve the same goal:

```
# save us some typing, shorten line length and maybe
# even perform better because of aliasing:
ob = bpy.context.object

ob.name = ob.name.replace("_HP", "_LP")
```

Limit number of replacements to 1:

```
name = bpy.context.object.name
name = name.replace("_HP", "_LP", 1)
```

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.name = re.sub("_HP$", "_LP", ob.name, 1)
```

Note: it will only substitute `_HP` once, and only if it's at the very end of ob.name!  It is equivalent to the following:

```
if ob.name.endswith("_HP"):
    ob.name = ob.name[:-3] + "_LP"
```